# On $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ find a generator of $(x^7+2x^4+x^3+x+3, x^4+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Prove that $\forall f,g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ we have $I:=(f,g)=(f+g,f-g)=:J$, is it true on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? Then on $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ find a generator of $(x^7+2x^4+x^3+x+3, x^4+1)$

About the first point, my solution is not that elegant but I think it works:

since $f+g \in I$ and $f-g\in I$ then $J \subseteq I$. Moreover $f=\frac{1}{2} (f+g)+\frac{1}{2} (f-g)\in J$ and $g=\frac{1}{2} (f+g)-\frac{1}{2} (f-g)\in J$ then $I \subseteq J$. So $I=J$.

It doesn't work on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$: if $f=1$ and $g=2$ then $f-g=-1$ which is invertible.

Using the fact that in a commutative ring $R$ we have $(a,b)=\{ax+by\,\, |\,\, x,y\in R\}$. So about the second point should I write the generator in that way? Which means the gcd (?).

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* $(f,g)=(\gcd(f,g))$, which can be found with the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

$$  \left(   x^{7}  + 2 x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x  + 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{7}  + 2 x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x  + 3 \right)  =  \left(   x^{4}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  + 2 \right) } +  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( 2  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  =  \left( 2  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  + 2 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{3}  + 2 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  - 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{6}  -  x^{5}  +  x^{4}  +  x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 2 x  - 1 \right) }{ \left(   x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  - 1 \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x^{7}  + 2 x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x  + 3 }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  x^{4}  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{7}  + 2 x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x  + 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{4}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{6}  -  x^{5}  +  x^{4}  +  x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 2 x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$